# Questions about HTT lemma 4.1.3.2

Tags: higher-category-theory

Set $C\rightarrow D\in sSet_{/S}$ a categorical equivalence over $S$, $E\rightarrow S$ a categorical fibration. Why is $Map_S(D,E)\rightarrow Map_S(C,E)$ still a categorical equivalence?

When $S=*$, this is well-known.

I met this problem in the proof of Lurie's HTT lemma 4.1.3.2.